# Get the second children of the parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically have this generated html and I need to get into the input element (the second child of the div) and take his value.

I started from the first child button and I managed to get to the parent `<div>` by using `var parent = $(elem).closest("div");` (this in a javascript function called with the onClick event).

I then saved the parent in a variable and now I'm trying to get to the second element without results. I tried everything but I'm just not able to get in there even with `closest()` starting from the first button.

I can't use any id or anything like that to search for the elements, I need to get there by navigating the DOM, any solution?

```
<div class="px-3" id="' . $row["idEvent"] . '">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-minus" onClick="decreaseQuantity(this)"></i></button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-25 d-inline" value="' . $row["TicketQuantity"] . '">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: If event is on  the first button can use `$(elem).next()`

Comment: already tried it, doesn't work. Yes the event is on the first button.

Comment: Show how the onclick is set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function decreaseQuantity(e){
var closestdiv = jQuery(e).parent();

var inputval = closestdiv.find('input').val();
alert(inputval);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="px-3" id="event">
     <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" onClick="decreaseQuantity(this)">Minus<i class="fas fa-minus" ></i></button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-25 d-inline" value="2">
     <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle">Plus<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
 </div>
```

Please try this. I hope you will get your answer

Comment: the "var closestdiv = jQuery(e).parent();" didn't work, but I used my "var parent = $(elem).closest("div");" that works and I tried your find method and it worked so I give you correct answer, thanks. Any reason why jQuery(e).parent(); didn't work? it just gives me "undefined" if I try to print for example with console.log jQuery(e).parent().attr('id'), but with my closest() it gives me the id. Any idea why?

Comment: This is due to , you have added onClick="decreaseQuantity(this)" in i tag. 

If you add onClick="decreaseQuantity(this)" in button tag then my method works

Comment: ...That was a very stupid mistake due to distraction, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` will always traverse the DOM upward until it finds a match.

There are multiple ways to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Here's 3 ways of doing it

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  alert(parent.find('input').val());
  
  //OR
  alert(parent.children('input').val());
  
  //OR
  alert($(this).siblings('input').val());
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="px-3">
  <button class=" btn bg-light border rounded-circle">
    -
  </button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control w-25 d-inline" value="value">
  <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle">
    +
  </button>
</div>
```

This code works well as long as you don't have more than one input field.
If you had more that one `input` field, you would need to access the `input` field with a `class`.

Comment: Thank you very much, they are all correct but they didn't want to work because I had made a distraction mistake in the generated HTML. Thumbs up.